# Почему действия не выполняются постепенно?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня программа рисует линии по вертикали и выставляет их по порядку с самых низких по высокие.
Почему сортировка проходит сразу а не постепенно?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

sc = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600))
FPS = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

y = [230,240,270,210,300,220]

def draw(xOne,yOne,xTwo,yTwo,Width):
    pygame.draw.line(sc,(0,0,255),(xOne,yOne),(xTwo,yTwo), Width)

while True:
    sc.fill((255,255,255))
    draw(200,400,200,y[0],10)   
    draw(250,400,250,y[1],10)   
    draw(300,400,300,y[2],10)   
    draw(350,400,350,y[3],10)   
    draw(400,400,400,y[4],10)   
    draw(450,400,450,y[5],10)   

    for h in pygame.event.get():
        if h.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    for i in range(len(y)):

        for j in range(len(y) - i - 1):

            if y[j] < y[j+1]:
                y[j], y[j+1] = y[j+1], y[j]     


    pygame.display.update()             
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: для ответа на вопрос "почему" нужно знать как устроена библиотека изнурти. Могу лишь предположить не сильно вникая в вопрос: там используются потоки.

Comment: Потому что в данном коде нет никаких причин для того, чтобы что-то выполнялось постепенно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(y)):

        for j in range(len(y) - i - 1):

            if y[j] < y[j+1]:
                y[j], y[j+1] = y[j+1], y[j]
```

Этот кусок полностью сортирует массив, чтобы он сортировал постепенно нужно сделать так:

```
for i in range(len(y) - 1):
    if y[i] < y[i + 1]:
        y[i], y[i + 1] = y[i + 1], y[i]
```